# Flask Python: Storing time-series data in a database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, time-series

I have a simple question that I may be overcomplicating, but what is the best way to store time-series data for a flask application?

I'm going to run a scheduled process in flask that calls to a weather api every hour and stores that data in a database. Each location (there are 300 hundred) will have the same timestamp (at the start of the hour) followed by the weather at that location.

Would a simple sqlite file storage work fine, or do I need a time-series database to store the data properly?